# python OSError: [Errorno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

When I execute the next python script in ubuntu 14.04 with python 2.7:

```
./marathon_lb.py --marathon http://172.16.8.231:8080 --group external
```

It throws the next error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./marathon_lb.py", line 1441, in <module>
    args.ssl_certs, ConfigTemplater())
  File "./marathon_lb.py", line 1130, in regenerate_config
    ssl_certs, templater), config_file)
  File "./marathon_lb.py", line 933, in compareWriteAndReloadConfig
    if writeConfigAndValidate(config, config_file):
  File "./marathon_lb.py", line 906, in writeConfigAndValidate
    returncode = subprocess.call(args=cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your python file marathon_lb.py line 906

```
returncode = subprocess.call(args=cmd)
```

use `subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)`

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to tell without your actual source code but error #2 usually happens when it can't find a file or a directory component.

Given that you have a call to `writeConfigAndValidate` in your stack trace, you should probably start by investigating what file is actually being written.

There's a good chance (given that it's writing) that you're trying to write to something like `/foo/bar/xyzzy.plugh` and there is no `/foo/bar` directory.